# How to calculate percentage in an SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Sql Server 2014

Table `Pricelist` with three columns: `Id, StoreId (Sid), Price`

```
Data format

Id  Sid Price
1   12    $4 
1   16    $2
2   12    $6
2   16    $10
```

What I am trying to do is have a procedure that compares **Store 12** prices with **Store 16** and if individual item prices are cheaper in one store than in the other then calculate the percentage savings and insert into a separate table OR in a Saving column next to the price column

The following SQL code displays % savings but I am not sure if I am doing it in the most efficient manner.

```
select distinct p1.[Store id],
case when p1.Price>p2.Price then (100*(p1.Price-p2.Price)/p1.Price) 
else (100*(p2.Price-p1.Price)/p2.Price)
end as Saving
from Prices$ p1
join Prices$ p2
on p1.[Item Id]=p2.[Item Id]
```

Please advice.

Thank you.

RG

Comment: You want to add `and p1.[store id] <> p2.[store id]` to the end so you're not comparing the same store. And you don't know what the other store is. is that important? Also `distinct` is extra work. Establish whether you really need it.

Comment: Better use `p1.[store id]<p2.[store id]` to avoid calculating the percentage for the same store combination twice

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This logic `p1.[store id]<p2.[store id]` will omit the last store id